# Add text at the end of the score in LilyPond

Tags: lilypond, lyrics

Is it possible to add a text at the end of the score like in [this example](https://www.srichinmoysongs.com/_media/auto/urdhe-amar-sunil-akash-dake-amar-jiban/urdhe-amar-sunil-akash-dake-amar-jiban_99ed1.jpg?cache=)?
[image: Score with addition text written after the end of the piece]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is very simple.

In your lilypond file, you can use any number of `\score` and `\markup` blocks, one after another, and Lilypond just typesets it all and puts it into one file in the same order. So here you would have

```
(...)
\score { (your score goes here) }
\markup {This text will appear below the score.}
```

Here's a [lilybin for you](http://lilybin.com/7egtmg/2) to experiment with (Lilybin is an online app that makes it possible to share Lilypond snippets. It can also render them right in your browser, so you can see the results).